# SASS functions check if value is map returns error

Tags: css, sass

I want to check if the value provides to a function is a map or not.

```
@function func($props...) {
      @if(is-map($props)) {
        @return 'something';
      }
      @else {}
    } 


h1 {
  color: func((color: red));
}
```

I'm getting the error:

> (color: red) isn't a valid CSS value.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because function returns map. Not a color as expected. Use [`map-get`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#map_get-instance_method) to get the access to properties values.

`@return map-get($props, color);`

And you have the variable argument. To get the first of arguments use `nth($props, 1)`.

Sassmeister [demo](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/78449b01b49535791e0aa6d2becfdbe3).

**Update**

If parameters in map are dynamic you can use this mixin instead of function.

```
@mixin print($declarations) {
  @if $declarations {
    @each $property, $value in $declarations {
      #{$property}: $value
    }
  } @else {
    @error "mixin print: $declarations is not specified";
  }
}
```

Mixin sassmeister [demo](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/1208f47420508c2875b2bd6d891bf03a).

Comment: The parameter is dynamic, I can't rely on a specific key.

Comment: You did not understand the question. I just want to the if the value is of type map.

Comment: https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/8226ca212c4f57e64994c399b4f636ef no error

Answer (score 2):

I personally never heard about any native Sass function called `is-map`. If you want to check the type of something, use the [type-of](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#type_of-instance_method) function, so for example, checking for `type-of($props) == map` would solve your problem in this case.

```
@function func($props...) {
  @if(type-of($props) == map) {
    @return 'something';
  }
  @else {}
}
```